Airflow DAG ignores custom MongoDB connection, uses mongo_default instead
I'm facing an issue with Apache Airflow where my DAG is not using the custom MongoDB connection I've defined. Instead, it's defaulting to the 'mongo_default' connection. This is causing problems with my workflow as it's not connecting to the correct MongoDB instance.
What I've done:

Created a custom MongoDB connection in the Airflow UI (Admin > Connections) with a specific connection ID (e.g., 'my_mongo_conn').

In my DAG, I'm using this custom connection:
from airflow.providers.mongo.hooks.mongo import MongoHook

def my_task():
    mongo_hook = MongoHook(mongo_conn_id='my_mongo_conn')
    # rest of the code...

my_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='my_mongo_task',
    python_callable=my_task,
    dag=dag
)





Expected behavior:
The DAG should use the 'my_mongo_conn' connection I defined in the Airflow UI.
Actual result:
When I run the DAG, Airflow ignores my custom connection and tries to use 'mongo_default' instead. here what i saw in logs
[2024-08-20T13:19:09.433+0000] {base.py:84} INFO - Using connection ID 'mongo_default' for task execution. but I want to use 'my_mongo_conn' like I wrote in my dag file.
I've verified that:
The connection ID in the UI matches exactly what I'm using in the DAG.
The connection details in the UI are correct.
I've saved the connection in the UI and restarted the Airflow webserver and scheduler.
Environment:
Airflow version: 2.9.3
Deployment method: docker-compose
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
I'm looking for insights on why Airflow might be ignoring my custom connection, how to force it to use the specified connection, or how to debug this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What version of mongo providers package is installed?

latest version 4.2.0

Could you try changing the 'mongo_conn_id' to 'conn_id', the connection arg was recently switched in the hook. I think that it's using an older version of the provider.
